# Query/Where dialog in Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

In Oracle Forms 6i, you could enter query mode in your form, and type **&** or **:A** in a field, and when you executed the query, a Query/Where dialog box would open, allowing you to enter more complex query or sorting criteria than just entering data in the fields allows.

This doesn't seem to work in Forms 10g: I get a "FRM-40367: Invalid Criteria in field XX in example record" error.

Is there some way to do this in Oracle Forms 10g?  We're running web-based, not client-server, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the answer after I posted this question here.  In 10g forms, this functionality is disabled by default, but can be enabled by setting

```
FORMS_RESTRICT_ENTER_QUERY=FALSE
```

in the default.env file.  We have now enabled this in our test environment, and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality used to be in Oracle eBusiness Suite, but possibly was removed I think due to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Not sure if there is a way to switch it back on - worth a look on http://metalink.oracle.com.
Regards,
Gareth